# Using Regex to Match Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex to retrieve Title:Code pair.

```
(.*?\(CPT-.*?\)|.*?\(ICD-.*?\))
```

Data:

SENSORINEURAL HEARING LOSS BILATERAL (MILD) (ICD-389.18) RIGHT WRIST GANGLION CYST (ICD-727.41) S/P INJECTION OF DEPO MEDROL INTO LEFT SHOULDER JOINT (CPT-20600)

I would like to capture:

- SENSORINEURAL HEARING LOSS BILATERAL (MILD) (ICD-389.18)
- RIGHT WRIST GANGLION CYST (ICD-727.41)
- S/P INJECTION OF DEPO MEDROL INTO LEFT SHOULDER JOINT (CPT-20600)

What is the proper regex to use?

Comment: Your capture example #1 and #2 both include `RIGHT WRIST`, is this intentional?

Comment: @jmstoker: No, i don't think, since the "hearing loss" is "bilateral" and not located on the "right wrist"

Comment: @jmstoker I agree with *Casimir*. See [ICD-389.18](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume1/320-389/380-389/389/389.18.htm) and [ICD-727.41](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume1/710-739/725-729/727/727.41.htm)

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not familiar with ICD codes, but looking at it further your comments make sense.

Comment: You has reassured us!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your regex. Implement using SingleLine(DOT-ALL), then strip out the newlines from the captures.

Comment: My bad, you have to use something like this `.*?\((?:CPT|ICD)-.*?\)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a pattern like this:

```
.*?\((CPT|ICD)-[A-Z0-9.]+\)
```

This will match zero or more of any character, non-greedily, followed by a `(` followed by either `CPT` or `ICD`, followed by a hyphen, followed by one or more Uppercase Latin letters, decimal digits or periods, followed by a `)`.

Note that I picked `[A-Z0-9.]+` because, to my understanding, all current [ICD-9 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICD-9_codes) , [ICD-10 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10), and [CPT codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_Procedural_Terminology) conform to that pattern.

The C# code might look a bit like this:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @".*?\((CPT|ICD)-[A-Z0-9.]+\)")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Value);
```

If you want to avoid having any surrounding whitespace, you simply trim the result strings (`m => m.Value.Trim()`), or ensure that the matched prefix starts with a non-whitespace character by putting a `\S` in front, like this:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\S.*?\((CPT|ICD)-[A-Z0-9.]+\)")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Value);
```

Or using a negative lookahead if you need to handle inputs like `(ICD-100)(ICD-200)`:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?!\s).*?\((CPT|ICD)-[A-Z0-9.]+\)")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Value);
```

You can see a working [demonstration here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F!%5Cs%29.%2a%3F%5C%28%28CPT%7CICD%29-%5BA-Z0-9.%5D%2B%5C%29&input=SENSORINEURAL%20HEARING%20LOSS%20BILATERAL%20%28MILD%29%20%28ICD-389.18%29%20RIGHT%20WRIST%20GANGLION%20CYST%20%28ICD-727.41%29%20S%2FP%20INJECTION%20OF%20DEPO%20MEDROL%20INTO%20LEFT%20SHOULDER%20JOINT%20%28CPT-20600%29).

Comment: Your regex places a space in front of the 2nd and 3rd match.  The space can be moved to the end by adding a `[ ]*` (space) to the end of your pattern. `.*?\((CPT|ICD)-[A-Z0-9.]+\)[ ]*`

Comment: @jmstoker That's a good point. But in case OP doesn't want to capture the surrounding whitespace at all, he'd need something a little different. I've provided a few alternatives.

Comment: +1 - I think its a toss-up between runaway errant text and flexibility. Erant text will not return partial result, flexibility might return too much ie: `\(ICD-[^)]*\)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method:

```
string input = "SENSORINEURAL HEARING LOSS BILATERAL (MILD) (ICD-389.18) RIGHT WRIST GANGLION CYST (ICD-727.41) S/P INJECTION OF DEPO MEDROL INTO LEFT SHOULDER JOINT (CPT-20600)";
string pattern = @"(?<=\))\s*(?=[^\s(])";
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
.*?\d\)
```

Good Luck!